# Bootstrap Responsive Images Scaling

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, background-image

Using `Twitter Bootstrap` I realize that by default it scales images responsively. This is great, but isn't always perfect.

Say for example I have a `500x300` image on desktop, then it resizes for mobile that image is going to be really small and not very tall, losing much of the detailed parts of the image.

I have seen how other sites actually don't scale the image much, but rather use the parent div to sort of `mask` the image. (http://www.fitnessfireworks.com was a great example of this, no longer available.)

What is the best method to accomplish this? A combination of `CSS` background-image and background image scaling? Just looking for best practices.

Answer (score 15):

> I have seen how other sites actually don't scale the image much, but rather use the parent div to sort of mask the image

If you examine the `CSS` on the page you mention, you will see that rather than using imline images, they are typically defining divs with background images, and using `CSS` like

```
#some-div {
background-size: 100%;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
vertical-align: top;
background-image: url(/.../image.jpg);
}
```

Here's an example of how you can get completely different results with scaling of inline image vs `background-image`.

http://www.bootply.com/67094

The key to the second method is to use background-size:cover and manipulate the size of the div (and hence the size of the background-image).

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/ has good info about variations and options with `background-cover`.

Answer (score 1):

You may find [this](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/10/how-to-avoid-duplicate-downloads-in-responsive-images/) article useful. It explains about optimizing images for responsive display and avoiding multiple image downloads

Answer (score 0):

If image quality is important I'd use two images using different class declaration. External tools will always be better at scaling images than the browser doing it on-the-fly.

Comment: Yes, quality is. I also plan to use 2x images so that they look nice on desktop retina screens.