# Bootstrap image getting cut off

Tags: image, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap Masthead img thats great when its full size , but as I shrink the page the entire ~25%  of the top and bottom get cut off. Of all the things on the page I want this to just scale correctly. I tried width:100% but that don't work

```
 padding-top: 10rem;
   padding-bottom: calc(10rem - 56px);
   background-image: url("../img/Am/20180904_094438cropped.jpg");
   background-position: center center;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
```

Thanks

Comment: maybe this helps- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45355016/bootstrap-page-header-background-image

Comment: Also check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit. Probably `scale-down` will help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting your code into a container div. It may look something along the lines of:

```
.container {
padding-top: 10 rem;
padding-bottom: calc(10rem - 56px);
background-image: url("../img/AM/20180904_094438cropped.jpg");
background-position: center center;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

Additionally, I found this reference for you: [similar topic on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579573/bootstrap-responsive-images-scaling)

I think it may help. Your code looks just about the same, however the width 100%, is a bit different! Check it out.